# Is there any solution why I am getting values different from database when calling an api from angular?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular7

I have been working with C# Web Api and angular 7, but i have come through some abnormal behavior. I have a UUID column in my database,when testing the api through url header it return the same UUID but when I call the Api from my angular app the UUID reurned isnt same as that was stored in DB.I am using MYSql for my database. PS I am attaching image for more explaination

[UUID I get when Testing from url header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueOC6.png)

[UUID when calling api from angular web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuXeF.png)

I have my uuid set as "long" and this is how i retrieve it in my C# code

```
public long id { get; set; }

   f.id = Convert.ToInt64(reader["id"]);
```

and my database UUID column is

```
id BIGINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

CREATE TRIGGER xyz BEFORE INSERT ON abc FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.id=0 THEN
        SET new.id = uuid_short();
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Your screenshot for "api from angular 7" is showing result of calling api "FetchTopRecords", not "FetchRollHeaderBetweenRoll".  Also, your code sample shows the setting from column "mac_id", but the problem is with the column "id".

Comment: oh my bad let me clear it

Comment: Thanks for the update.  If the "View Roll Report" is calling the exact same URL as that shown in the browser image, then they must be identical - so I can only guess that there is some difference in the URL.  Could you paste the "Headers" tab for that "View Roll Report" as well, showing the full URL ?

Comment: the header url of C# is "http://localhost:51072/Api/FetchingRollReport/FetchRollReport"
The url that my angular hit is also same i.e "http://localhost:51072/Api/FetchingRollReport/FetchRollReport"

Comment: the strange thing here is that my database doesnt even  have any "id" that my angular app  shows I dont know why is that so from where its getting that value is it rounding off the value?

Comment: Longs should be represented as strings in JavaScript or else you risk losing precision. long.MaxValue > number.MAX_SAFE_VALUE